# Get FingerPrint/VoicePrint of a micro recorded audio in android

Tags: android, audio, voice-recognition, fingerprint, audio-fingerprinting

I am trying to see if it is viable this...thanks all in advance :)

I want to make an app, that recognize some audio taken from the microphone. For now i just need to get the fingerprint (or audioprint i don't know the exactly name in english ^^). A text like `"sjd78fhwHJsdjsDjwrkf"` or whatever it is the shape of a audio fingerprint.

I just need to know how to get the fingerprint of an audio in android, but i don't find a easy solution in all this audio recognition for java/android.

Thanks for all and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is what's called "audio fingerprinting". The only open source audio fingerprinting system I know of is called "echoprint" http://echoprint.me/

Comment: Hi Bjonr, i tryed that option, and it worked great. The problem now is that i am trying to listen simultanually with several AudioRecords at the same time, but the instantation of AudioRecord crash always on the second if the first one is noit released.

Is it posible to have several AudioRecords listening at the same time? Or it is just a problem of emulator?

Thx

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but sounds like you should open a separate question.

Comment: Yeah... i already did this morning here in this link.. [Several instances simultaneously of AudioRecord crashing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299214/is-it-possibly-to-have-sumultaneously-two-instances-of-audiorecord-with-echoprin) . Thanks by the way ;)